# Erro ao executar o Eclipse após instalação do Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, instalador, windows-10

Quando utilizava o **Windows 8** o Eclipse funcionava normalmente, agora que instalei o **Windows 10** sempre que tento executar tenho está mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou executa-lo em modo de compatibilidade?

Comment: O Eclipse é 64bits e o W10 é 64bits?

Comment: Entre na pasta do workspace em seguida a `.metadata` abra o arquivo `.log` coloque a mensagem de erro mais recente na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maioria das aplicações do ambiente de trabalho escritas para o **Windows 7** e para o **Windows 8.1** também funcionam no **Windows 10**, mas é possível que algumas aplicações antigas funcionem mal ou nem sequer funcionem. Se uma aplicação mais antiga não funcionar corretamente, execute a **Resolução de Problemas para Compatibilidade de Programas**. Para tal:

> Não execute a Resolução de Problemas de Compatibilidade de Programas
>   em programas antivírus, software de firewall, software de cópia de
>   segurança, utilitários de disco ou programas de sistema fornecidos com
>   o Windows. Este procedimento poderá originar perda de dados ou criar
>   um risco de segurança.

- Passo 1:     Clique em <kbd>Windows</kbd>  e escreva executar programas.
- Passo 2:     Nos resultados da pesquisa, selecione Executar programas criados para versões anteriores do Windows.
- Passo 3:     Na Resolução de Problemas de Compatibilidade de Programas, selecione Seguinte e siga as instruções apresentadas no ecrã.

Detalhes

- [Resolução de problemas de aplicações de ambiente de trabalho](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/pt-pt/support/apps-and-windows-store/troubleshoot-desktop-apps-on-surface?os=windows-10&=undefined)